# How to print line for specific conditions using lxml in a long XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

XML example as follows:

```
<File>
    <Sub_Function_1>
        <Messages>
            <Setting>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_2</Label>
                    <Value>
                        <Measure>
                            <Data>Area_2</Data>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Speed>2000</Speed>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>0</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                            <Bound>
                                <Value>
                                    <Distance>10000</Distance>
                                </Value>
                                <Condition>
                                    <Data>12000</Data>
                                </Condition>
                            </Bound>
                        </Measure>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
                <Data>
                    <Label>Setting_3</Label>
                    <Value>
                        <Default_value_if_undefined>
                            <Value>
                                <Value_on_condition>
                                    <Case>
                                        <Value>
                                            <Measure>
                                                <Speed>25</Speed>
                                                <Bound>
                                                    <Value>
                                                        <Time>2000</Time>
                                                    </Value>
                                                    <Condition>
                                                        <Speed>0</Speed>
                                                    </Condition>
                                                </Bound>
                                                <Bound>
                                                    <Value>
                                                        <Distance>10000</Distance>
                                                    </Value>
                                                    <Condition>
                                                        <Speed>12000</Speed>
                                                    </Condition>
                                                </Bound>
                                            </Measure>
                                        </Value>
                                        <Condition>
                                            <Data>Area_0</Data>
                                        </Condition>
                                    </Case>
                                </Value_on_condition>
                            </Value>
                            <Default_value>
                                <Integer>2000</Integer>
                            </Default_value>
                        </Default_value_if_undefined>
                    </Value>
                </Data>
            </Setting>
        </Messages>
    </Sub_Function_1>
</File>
```

Code is as follows:

```
for k in doc2.xpath('//Measure//Data[following-sibling::Bound]'):
    val1 = k.xpath('following-sibling::Bound[1]/Value/*')[0]
    val2 = k.xpath('following-sibling::Bound[2]/Value/*')[0]
    if val1.tag !=val2.tag:
        print("val:",val1.tag,"--",val1.sourceline,val2.tag,"--",val2.sourceline)

for k in doc2.xpath('//File[.//Measure//Data[following-sibling::Bound]]'):
    val1 = k.xpath('.//Measure//Data[following-sibling::Bound[1]/Value/*[1]]')
    val2 = k.xpath('.//Measure//Data[following-sibling::Bound[2]/Value/*[1]]')
    if val1 != val2:
        print("val:",val1, "--", val1.sourceline, val2, "--", val2.sourceline)
```

Output i am getting :

```
val: Speed -- 13 Distance -- 21
```

Output i am expecting:

```
val: Speed -- 13 Distance -- 21
val: Time -- 42 Distance -- 50
```

I was printing lines when both  or  has different attribute as shown in snapshot

for some reason it's not printing for all  element such as if its inside "<Value_on_condition>" in 'Setting_3' in xml
So if its a long xml its not able to find measure and compare both Val1 and Val2

[image]

Comment: Data always comes before Measure. To see all possible Xpaths on an XML try [xml2xpath](https://github.com/mluis7/xml2xpath) shell script.

Comment: @LMC
even "[.//Data//Measure[following-sibling::Bound]" is not printing
i was referring https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14
not able to find solution from here also

Comment: Bound is not a sibling of Measure, it's a child or descendant. Siblings are those elements with same parent.

Comment: @LMC But there are two Bounds and both have same parent Measure. So if to consider both Bound they will be sibling

Comment: Those 2 Bounds are siblings but `Measure[following-sibling::Bound]` means Measure and Bound are siblings. Please read about XPath axis.

Comment: @LMC Ok, changed to `Measure[child::Bound]` , still no result
can you refer some links for XPath axis

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the xml in this question is different from the one in your other question. To reflect that, change your `for` loop to this:

```
for k in doc2.xpath('//Value//Measure'):
    val1 = k.xpath('.//Bound[1]//Value/*')[0]
    val2 = k.xpath('.//Bound[2]//Value/*')[0]
    if val1.tag !=val2.tag:
        print(val1.tag,"--",val1.sourceline,val2.tag,"--",val2.sourceline)
   
    cond1 = k.xpath('.//Bound[1]//Condition/*')[0]
    cond2 = k.xpath('.//Bound[2]//Condition/*')[0]
    if cond1.tag !=cond2.tag:
        print(cond1.tag,"--",cond1.sourceline,val2.tag,"--",cond2.sourceline)
```

The output I get is

```
Speed -- 12 Distance -- 20
Time -- 41 Distance -- 49
```